# JMS Point to Point Jmeter Load Testing - NoInitialContextException

Tags: jmeter, jms

I was trying to test JMS using Jmeter and was trying to run it in local, but keep getting the error:
Response message: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory]

I have already added the activemq-all.jar file in lib folder of jmeter, which should have resolved the issue, but it remains.

Please help me understand if I am missing something. Thanks.

Below is my jmx file content for the test plan:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.0 r1840935">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="JMS P2P Load Test" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="JMSTestPlan-P2P" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">2</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">0</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <JMSSampler guiclass="JMSSamplerGui" testclass="JMSSampler" testname="JMS Point-to-Point" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="JMSSampler.queueconnectionfactory">ConnectionFactory</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="JMSSampler.SendQueue">Q.REQ</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="JMSSampler.ReceiveQueue">Q.REQ</stringProp>
          <intProp name="JMSSampler.communicationStyle">0</intProp>
          <boolProp name="JMSSampler.isNonPersistent">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="JMSSampler.useReqMsgIdAsCorrelId">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="JMSSampler.timeout">2000</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="JMSSampler.jmsNumberOfSamplesToAggregate"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSamper.xml_data">Testing point to point</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="JMSSampler.initialContextFactory">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="JMSSampler.contextProviderUrl">tcp://localhost:61616</stringProp>
          <elementProp name="JMSSampler.jndiProperties" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
              <elementProp name="queue.Q.REQ" elementType="Argument">
                <stringProp name="Argument.name">queue.Q.REQ</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.value">example.A</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="arguments" elementType="JMSProperties">
            <collectionProp name="JMSProperties.properties"/>
          </elementProp>
          <boolProp name="JMSSampler.useResMsgIdAsCorrelId">true</boolProp>
        </JMSSampler>
        <hashTree/>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
              <url>true</url>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
              <idleTime>true</idleTime>
              <connectTime>true</connectTime>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test plan looks good, most probably you forgot one little step: **you need to restart JMeter in order to pick up the new .jars from its [classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)**

If you want quickly test a .jar without JMeter restart you can add on [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level

[image]

You might also be interested in [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter) guide which covers [JMeter official documentation on JMS testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-point-to-point-test-plan.html) gaps.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I am kicking myself for not thinking about this myself.